# Django 1.7 Models aren't loaded yet when getting foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I have a Class which will be called by the project `__init__.py`(because I want to save the value in memory when `django` website start ) :

```
def get_rec(**karg):
    try: 
       if len(karg) == 0:
          return Gateway.objects.all()
       else:
          return Gateway.objects.filter(**karg)
    except as e:
       log.error(e)
       return []

Class test(object):

    def __init_rec_list(object):
        rec = get_rec()
        for r in rec:
            print r.mac_address
            print r.area.area_name
```

But it will get error when it try to print `r.area.area_name`:

```
  raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Why can't it print `r.area.area_name`??

Here is the models.py

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

class Gateway(models.Model):  
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'area')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call django dependent initialisation  code after django loads. Only when django.setup() runs, the App registry is ready.

The correct entry point, assuming you have the default wsgi.py file, is in the wsgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")    
application = get_wsgi_application() # this prepares django 
my_init_code()
```

If you absolutely need to run things before the models load, use direct SQL to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it clearly - models are not ready yet. The earlier moment you can touch database is in [AppConfig.ready](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), but it has still some limitations.

If you want to safely use all models, put the code into `urls.py` in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the model in an `__init__.py` file, you are creating a chicken and egg scenario. The init code requires the models ready and the models are waiting for the `__init__.py` to be ready.

It is not a good practice, calling this type of codes in `__init__.py` file. Because this file is loaded not only for django start up but also whenever you are importing the module.

From you code, I can see you are trying to access users ip and other information based on that.

The best way would be using a custom `middleware` to intercept the `request/response` and updating the `request/response` object based on the values.

something similar to this -

```
class CustomMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        rec = get_rec()
        request.rec = rec;
```

Now you can access the property `rec` of `request` and use anyway you like.

You can read more about middlewares here -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: If an action is required only once at startup, it's better not to put it in a middleware that runs for every request

Comment: @AviahLaor agreed, but I didn't answer to put something in the memory for startup, I answered OP's scenario, tracking mac, its better to do that in each request. User can easily change mac and that has nothing to do with django startup.